# Inset image thumbnail from page into list

Tags: wp-list-pages

I currently have 10 child pages which each contain one main image and text.

I then have the main parent page, which acts as a 'contents page'.

I currently have this code on the main parent page...

```
<ul class="treatments-list h3">
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID=15); ?>
</ul>
```

This gets all the titles for these child pages and lists them, however, I would like to add an image thumbnail at the start of each of these lists, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the image in the post body?

Comment: yes it is in the body

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_pages to do that:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => get_the_ID())); ?> 
<ul class="treatments-list h3">
    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
            <h2>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($page->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($page->post_title);?>">
                    <?php echo $page->post_title; ?>
                </a>
            </h2>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but it does not seem to work. I have added the additional code in functions also but the image does not appear